# How to set conditional rules and required fields in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to make few fields conditionally required. But I am not able to make it work. I have set a data field `notRequired: false` and based on that I am using it in the fields as `:required="!notRequired"` to make those fields as not required because in some cases I need those fields as required and in some cases I don't because of which I trying to set that conditionally. The issue is the error message still appears because of the rules which are added to the fields. Is there a way to make the rules conditional too?

```
<template>
 <v-text-field
  label='Agency Name'
  v-model='agency.name'
  :rules='nameRules'
  :required="!notRequired"
  required>
 </v-text-field>
 <v-text-field
  label='Agency Code'
  :rules='codeRules'
  :required="!notRequired"
  v-model='agency.code'>
 </v-text-field>
 <v-text-field
  label='Agency location'
  :rules='locationRules'
  :required="notRequired"
  v-model='agency.location'>
 </v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      notRequired: false,
      agency: {
        name: '',
        code: '',
        location: '',
      }
      nameRules: [
        value => !!value || 'Please enter name'
      ],
      codeRules: [
        value => !!value || 'Please enter code'
      ],
      locationRules: [
        value => !!value || 'Please enter location'
      ],
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator to conditionally add rules, depending on the value of `notRequired`:

```html
 <v-text-field
   label="Agency Name"
   v-model="agency.name"
   :rules="notRequired ? 'nameRules' : []" <!-- HERE -->
   :required="!notRequired">
 </v-text-field>
```

Comment: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "rules". Expected Array, got String.
This is the error I am getting now

Comment: oops, yeah, passed empty string, pass an empty array instead `:rules="notRequired ? 'nameRules' : []"`